# Replace text contain key value pair in batch script in same file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=EikonPath"
set "replace=EikonPath": "D:\\e5\\desktopframework\\src\\products\\eikon-on-electron"
set "textFile=D:\e4\office-shim\src\eikon-office-shim\config\install-settings.json"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Replace this:

```
"EikonPath": "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Refinitiv\\Refinitiv Workspace"
```

to:

```
"EikonPath": "D:\\e5\\desktopframework\\src\\products\\eikon-on-electron"
```

The above approach gives:

```
"EikonPath": "D:\\e5\\desktopframework\\src\\products\\eikon-on-electron": "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Refinitiv\\Refinitiv Workspace",
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't replace your file *inline*.
Better redirect the output to a temporary file and then replace the original file.

The other problem, you try to replace not only the search string, instead you want the search string and the rest of the line.
I changed the code to replace the whole line with the `replace` variable

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=EikonPath"
set "replace="EikonPath": "D:\\e5\\desktopframework\\src\\products\\eikon-on-electron""
set "textFile=test.json"

(
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textFile%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if not "!line:%search%=!" == "!line!" (
            echo(!replace!
        ) else (
            echo(!line!
        )
        endlocal
    )
) > newfile.tmp
move /Y newfile.tmp "%textfile%"
```

Comment: I want to update the same file. I replaced `newfile.tmp` with existing file name but all the contents are deleted

Comment: @kitu What do you expect? Writing to the same file you are reading from, how  should it work? Therefore write to temporay file and later replace your original file with the temp file